# Can't do 301 Redirect, Why?

Tags: redirect

I just solved the 403 error on my website.com main page.
I was getting 403 error on website.com because it was permission error.
Here I've posted the previous question here:

[403 and 404 Wordpress Error on multiple web pages, how to resolve ?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/271620/403-and-404-wordpress-error-on-multiple-web-pages-how-to-resolve)

I've added html code which redirected to website.com/blog and it works.

But I'd like to do a 301 redirect now because I want to tell google (for the SEO) that website.com is working and it redirects to website.com/blog.

How can I do that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here you find out how to do what you want to do:
http://www.rapidtables.com/web/dev/htaccess-redirect.htm